# Show more than one topic edit history per page, like post edit history on main site

Tags: feature-request, documentation

It's pretty inconvenient that the view is limited to one edit per page and I want to be able to scroll the page to compare multiple edits, and not have to open new pages/tabs and wait for them to load and then switch between them.

I just realized the idea is to have a ton of edits per topic, and the history is likely to get huge over the years, but still there could be multiple edits shows per page if fetching all of them is too much load for the servers.

Comment: What happens when two of the edits conflict with each other, though?

Comment: I guess we'll need some sort of edit graph, like with version control systems.